# Apply one event to all textbox in a userform

Tags: c#, events

Parts of this topic as already been cover, but I'm new to C# and I can't quite figure it out.

I got a function which force the user to enter number with decimal

```
public void onlynumwithsinglepoint(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == '.'))
    { e.Handled = true; }
    TextBox txtDecimal = sender as TextBox;
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtDecimal.Text.Contains("."))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I need that function to be apply to every textbox in my form named ConcreteFilledColumn() when there is a KeyPress. I know there is a way using "for each" statement... but can't figure it out. Right now all my textbox use individual event like so:

```
private void columnLengthTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    onlynumwithsinglepoint(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: are your textbox dynamically created or manually created?

Comment: They are created manually

Comment: You can choose method in designer.

Answer (score 2):

It's as easy as this:

```
public Form1() //your form constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textbox1.OnKeyDown += onlynumwithsinglepoint; //or whatever the event is
    textbox2.OnKeyDown += onlynumwithsinglepoint; 
    textbox3.OnKeyDown += onlynumwithsinglepoint;
}
```

As for recursively, I'd guess something like this works, if you are using WinForms:

```
public Form1() //your form constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach(Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        b.OnkeyDown += onlynumwithsinglepoint; //or whatever the event is
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks cFrozenDeath, since I got 40+ textbox I was trying to find a way to loop them all using something like for each controls...

Comment: I think we are almost there. The only problem is that my function that apply restriction to the textbox (which does not come from me) seems to need some input parameters...   public void onlynumwithsinglepoint(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

Comment: That's the function declaration for an event, my syntax shows how to properly assign the event, using the += notation

Comment: @Phil, In that case you will have to define your own event argument class inheriting from `KeyPressEventArgs` class